# Bitmap Image Blur

Tags: c, bitmap, cs50, blur, bitmapimage

I am trying to box blur a bmp image in a problem set in cs50, the code I wrote successfully identifies a middle pixel which is surrounded by 8 others. The goal is to take the average value of red, green and blue of every pixel including the one we're studying and change every one of the three values to the average value, it seems to me that the code is correct but the result isn't. Considering I am taking the CS50 course, please use hints only and no code because it would be a violation of the course's rules.

```
void blur(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width])
{
    int avg_r = 0;
    int avg_g = 0;
    int avg_b = 0;
    RGBTRIPLE temp[height][width];
    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
        {
            float counter = 1.0;
            avg_r += image[i][j].rgbtRed;
            avg_g += image[i][j].rgbtGreen;
            avg_b += image[i][j].rgbtBlue;

            //first attempt

            // if (i != height - 1 || j != width - 1)
            // {
            //     avg_r += image[i + 1][j + 1].rgbtRed;
            //     avg_g += image[i + 1][j + 1].rgbtGreen;
            //     avg_b += image[i + 1][j + 1].rgbtBlue;
            //     counter += 1;
            // }
            // if (i != 0 || j != width - 1)
            // {
            //     avg_r += image[i - 1][j + 1].rgbtRed;
            //     avg_g += image[i - 1][j + 1].rgbtGreen;
            //     avg_b += image[i - 1][j + 1].rgbtBlue;
            //     counter += 1;
            // }
            // if (i != height - 1 || j != 0)
            // {
            //     avg_r += image[i + 1][j - 1].rgbtRed;
            //     avg_g += image[i + 1][j - 1].rgbtGreen;
            //     avg_b += image[i + 1][j - 1].rgbtBlue;
            //     counter += 1;
            // }
            // if (i != 0 || j != 0)
            // {
            //     avg_r += image[i - 1][j - 1].rgbtRed;
            //     avg_g += image[i - 1][j - 1].rgbtGreen;
            //     avg_b += image[i - 1][j - 1].rgbtBlue;
            //     counter += 1;
            // }
            // if (i != 0)
            // {
            //     avg_r += image[i - 1][j].rgbtRed;
            //     avg_g += image[i - 1][j].rgbtGreen;
            //     avg_b += image[i - 1][j].rgbtBlue;
            //     counter += 1;
            // }
            // if (j != 0)
            // {
            //     avg_r += image[i][j - 1].rgbtRed;
            //     avg_g += image[i][j - 1].rgbtGreen;
            //     avg_b += image[i][j - 1].rgbtBlue;
            //     counter += 1;
            // }
            // if (i != height - 1)
            // {
            //     avg_r += image[i + 1][j].rgbtRed;
            //     avg_g += image[i + 1][j].rgbtGreen;
            //     avg_b += image[i + 1][j].rgbtBlue;
            //     counter += 1;
            // }
            // if (j != width - 1)
            // {
            //     avg_r += image[i][j + 1].rgbtRed;
            //     avg_g += image[i][j + 1].rgbtGreen;
            //     avg_b += image[i][j + 1].rgbtBlue;
            //     counter += 1;
            // }
            //         avg_r = round(avg_r / counter);
            //         avg_g = round(avg_g / counter);
            //         avg_b = round(avg_b / counter);

            //         temp[i][j].rgbtGreen = avg_g;
            //         temp[i][j].rgbtBlue = avg_b;
            //         temp[i][j].rgbtRed = avg_r;

            //second attempt

                // if (i == 0)
                // {
                //     if (j == 0)
                //     {
                //         avg_r += image[i][j + 1].rgbtRed;
                //         avg_g += image[i][j + 1].rgbtGreen;
                //         avg_b += image[i][j + 1].rgbtBlue;

                //         counter += 1;

                //         avg_r += image[i + 1][j + 1].rgbtRed;
                //         avg_g += image[i + 1][j + 1].rgbtGreen;
                //         avg_b += image[i + 1][j + 1].rgbtBlue;

                //         counter += 1;

                //         avg_r += image[i + 1][j].rgbtRed;
                //         avg_g += image[i + 1][j].rgbtGreen;
                //         avg_b += image[i + 1][j].rgbtBlue;

                //         counter += 1;

                //         avg_r = round(avg_r / counter);
                //         avg_g = round(avg_g / counter);
                //         avg_b = round(avg_b / counter);

                //         temp[i][j].rgbtGreen = avg_g;
                //         temp[i][j].rgbtBlue = avg_b;
                //         temp[i][j].rgbtRed = avg_r;

                //         continue;
                //     }
                //     else if (j == width - 1)
                //     {
                //         avg_r += image[i][j + 1].rgbtRed;
                //         avg_g += image[i][j + 1].rgbtGreen;
                //         avg_b += image[i][j + 1].rgbtBlue;

                //         counter += 1;

                //         avg_r += image[i + 1][j].rgbtRed;
                //         avg_g += image[i + 1][j].rgbtGreen;
                //         avg_b += image[i + 1][j].rgbtBlue;

                //         counter += 1;

                //         avg_r += image[i + 1][j - 1].rgbtRed;
                //         avg_g += image[i + 1][j - 1].rgbtGreen;
                //         avg_b += image[i + 1][j - 1].rgbtBlue;

                //         counter += 1;

                //         avg_r = round(avg_r / counter);
                //         avg_g = round(avg_g / counter);
                //         avg_b = round(avg_b / counter);

                //         temp[i][j].rgbtGreen = avg_g;
                //         temp[i][j].rgbtBlue = avg_b;
                //         temp[i][j].rgbtRed = avg_r;

                //         continue;
                //     }
                //     else
                //     {
                //         avg_r += image[i][j + 1].rgbtRed;
                //         avg_g += image[i][j + 1].rgbtGreen;
                //         avg_b += image[i][j + 1].rgbtBlue;

                //         counter += 1;

                //         avg_r += image[i][j - 1].rgbtRed;
                //         avg_g += image[i][j - 1].rgbtGreen;
                //         avg_b += image[i][j - 1].rgbtBlue;

                //         counter += 1;

                //         avg_r += image[i + 1][j - 1].rgbtRed;
                //         avg_g += image[i + 1][j - 1].rgbtGreen;
                //         avg_b += image[i + 1][j - 1].rgbtBlue;

                //         counter += 1;

                //         avg_r += image[i + 1][j + 1].rgbtRed;
                //         avg_g += image[i + 1][j + 1].rgbtGreen;
                //         avg_b += image[i + 1][j + 1].rgbtBlue;

                //         counter += 1;

                //         avg_r += image[i + 1][j].rgbtRed;
                //         avg_g += image[i + 1][j].rgbtGreen;
                //         avg_b += image[i + 1][j].rgbtBlue;

                //         counter += 1;

                //         avg_r = round(avg_r / counter);
                //         avg_g = round(avg_g / counter);
                //         avg_b = round(avg_b / counter);

                //         temp[i][j].rgbtGreen = avg_g;
                //         temp[i][j].rgbtBlue = avg_b;
                //         temp[i][j].rgbtRed = avg_r;

                //         continue;
                //     }
                // }


            if (i != 0 && j != 0 && j != width - 1 && i != height - 1)
            {

                avg_r += image[i - 1][j - 1].rgbtRed;
                avg_b += image[i - 1][j - 1].rgbtBlue;
                avg_g += image[i - 1][j - 1].rgbtGreen;

                avg_r += image[i - 1][j].rgbtRed;
                avg_b += image[i - 1][j].rgbtBlue;
                avg_g += image[i - 1][j].rgbtGreen;

                avg_r += image[i - 1][j + 1].rgbtRed;
                avg_b += image[i - 1][j + 1].rgbtBlue;
                avg_g += image[i - 1][j + 1].rgbtGreen;

                avg_r += image[i][j - 1].rgbtRed;
                avg_b += image[i][j - 1].rgbtBlue;
                avg_g += image[i][j - 1].rgbtGreen;

                avg_r += image[i][j].rgbtRed;
                avg_b += image[i][j].rgbtBlue;
                avg_g += image[i][j].rgbtGreen;

                avg_r += image[i][j + 1].rgbtRed;
                avg_b += image[i][j + 1].rgbtBlue;
                avg_g += image[i][j + 1].rgbtGreen;

                avg_r += image[i + 1][j - 1].rgbtRed;
                avg_b += image[i + 1][j - 1].rgbtBlue;
                avg_g += image[i + 1][j - 1].rgbtGreen;

                avg_r += image[i + 1][j].rgbtRed;
                avg_b += image[i + 1][j].rgbtBlue;
                avg_g += image[i + 1][j].rgbtGreen;

                avg_r += image[i + 1][j + 1].rgbtRed;
                avg_b += image[i + 1][j + 1].rgbtBlue;
                avg_g += image[i + 1][j + 1].rgbtGreen;

                avg_r = round(avg_r / 9.0);
                avg_g = round(avg_g / 9.0);
                avg_b = round(avg_b / 9.0);

                temp[i][j].rgbtGreen = avg_g;
                temp[i][j].rgbtBlue = avg_b;
                temp[i][j].rgbtRed = avg_r;
            }


        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
        {
            image[i][j].rgbtGreen = temp[i][j].rgbtGreen;
            image[i][j].rgbtBlue = temp[i][j].rgbtBlue;
            image[i][j].rgbtRed = temp[i][j].rgbtRed;
        }
    }

    return;
}
```

You can see that I tried three different methods, but none of them work, please focus on the last one first (the non commented one) which identifies just middle pixels.

Comment: At the beginning of the inner loop, `avg_r += image[i][j].rgbtRed;` (etc) should be `avg_r = image[i][j].rgbtRed;`. And then you should revisit the pixel summation too.

Comment: why is that? even though I set it to 0 in the beginning?

Comment: Because you are summing *every pixel in the image* (nine times!) and with each location those sums gets bigger and bigger.

Comment: Oh, it gets bigger and bigger. I guess I should use long variables instead of ints, thank you very much

Comment: No. It is not supposed to get bigger and bigger. You are averaging a group of (up to) nine pixels, not all of them. Another option would be to move `int avg_r = 0; int avg_g = 0; int avg_b = 0;` inside the loop, to where you have `float counter = 1.0;`.

Comment: I've returned back to the first attempt where it uses a counter to count the number of times we added and according to the cs50 check mechanism it works fine, but when I actually use it on real images, the result is terrible. PS: I hardcoded the divide by 1 because the if statement selects middle pixels which have exactly nine pixels around it including itself to average

Comment: And yeah initializing it before the loop was an obvious mistake that I didn't notice, thank you

Comment: It is good now thank you very much I just didn't compile the code I'm so ashamed lol